# Create new database on the fly in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, multi-tenant

I want dynamically create new database, database user and password with privileges, create some tables in new database on the fly in Laravel 4 for every new user. This is for a multi tenant website.

Whats the best solution?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not your first database connection it's easy, but you'll have to execute raw statements because database creation is no available as connection methods:

```
DB::statement(DB::raw('CREATE DATABASE <name>'));
```

To do that you can use a secondary connection:

```
<?php
return array(

    'default' => 'mysql',

    'connections' => array(

        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'host1',
            'database'  => 'database1',
            'username'  => 'user1',
            'password'  => 'pass1'
        ),

        'store' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'host2',
            'database'  => 'database2',
            'username'  => 'user2',
            'password'  => 'pass2'
        ),
    ),
);
```

Then you can, during application bootstrap, change the database of the secondary connection:

```
DB::connection('store')->setDatabaseName($store);
```

or

```
Config::set('database.connections.store', $store);
```

And use the secondary connection in your queries:

```
$user = User::on('store')->find(1);
```

or

```
DB::connection('store')->select(...);
```